Latex decimal alignment issues- font changed, header affected, not aligning for bold maths
I'm a beginner of Latex and I'm working on a journal formatting.
I have a lot of statistical tables (ANOVA table, post-hoc test) to put into my paper, here are some problem I encountered:

Decimal alignment package meaning unclear to me: I used the dcolumn package for decimal alignment in each column. Although I've checked through the documentation of this package, it is still unclear to me what D{.}{.}{a,b} really does to the numerical values and text in the table.

For instance, below are one of my table code and its image:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\caption{COMPARISONS BETWEEN THE LFG AND THE ARG ON INTERCEPT}
\label{tab:compare_intercept_LFG_ARG}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|D{.}{.}{2,3}|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Mode} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Config. 1\\ (I)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Config. 2\\ (J)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{...}Mean Diff.\\ (I)-(J)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SE\\ Diff.\\ (I)-(J)\end{tabular}} &
  \textit{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}t\\ (df=31)\end{tabular}}} &
  \textit{\textbf{p}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{AR mode} & ARG-30 & LFG-30 & 70.952 & 30.067 & 2.360 & \textbf{.025*} \\ \cline{2-7} 
                         & ARG-60 & LFG-60 & 38.37  & 30.441 & 1.260 & .219           \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{VR mode} & ARG-30 & LFG-30 & 50.915 & 37.319 & 1.364 & .215           \\ \cline{2-7} 
                         & ARG-60 & LFG-60 & 48.637 & 32.534 & 1.495 & .794           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

This is what the code shows in PDF.
I changed from\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} to  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|D{.}{.}{2,3}|c|c|c|} for aligning the decimal point, but it caused the first row header to run out of the cell.

Error happens when I add D{.}{.}{number} as an alignment choice
The code below used D{.}{.}{3} and \boldmath{}, and it jumped several errors (listed below). But it turns out that the table shows quite well to me.

Missing } inserted. → I couldn't find the place

Extra }, or forgotten $. → I couldn't find any

Command \boldmath invalid in math mode on input line 62. → don't know why

Command \mathversion invalid in math mode on input line 62. → don't know either

Overfull \hbox (4.33331pt too wide) detected at line 62 → guess maybe I can ignore it?




\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{POST HOC TEST RESULTS OF THE INTERACTION FOR SLOPE BETWEEN GLASSES AND DISTANCE}
\label{tab:slope_2w_inter_glasses_dist}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|D{.}{.}{5}|D{.}{.}{3}|D{.}{.}{3}|D{.}{.}{3}|}
\hline 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Group\\ \#\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Config. 1\\ (I)\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Config. 2\\ (J)\end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mean Diff.\\ (I)$-$(J)\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SE}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}t\\ (df=31)\end{tabular}}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{p}}} \\ [3pt] \hline
1 & \multirow{3}{*}{ARG-30} & ARG-60 & 14.463   & 5.063 & 2.857   & \boldmath{.035^{*}} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
2 &                         & LFG-30 & 4.621    & 5.211 & 0.887   & 1.000          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
3 &                         & LFG-60 & 2.177    & 5.771 & 0.377   & 1.000          \\ \hline
4 & \multirow{2}{*}{LFG-30} & ARG-60 & 9.842    & 5.771 & 1.705   & .373           \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} 
5 &                         & LFG-60 & -2.444  & 5.063 & -0.483 & 1.000          \\ \hline
6 & ARG-60                  & LFG-60 & -12.286 & 5.211 & -2.358 & .109           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{$^{\ast}$\textit{p} \textless .05.}
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}


If I use \bm instead of \boldmath, the code collapse and couldn't compile. Furthurmore, if I add $$, such as $\bm{.35^{*}}$, the whold cell will go blank (same for \boldmath)

Font changes when I use D{.}{.}{} (happening to the 2nd code block above)
I found this alignment choice automatically add $$ to all the numerical cells such that the cells with non-math font will be changed to math style, and the math font with $$ in the corresponding columns will be change back to normal text.
Is there anyway to resolve this font-changing issue?

Bold math with asterisk * won't align by decimal point.
I have a lot of values need asterisk superscript (ex. .05* , .01**, .001***), but the same method for decimal alignment doesn't work for the cells with superscript.


I changed the value in D{.}{.}{#} like D{.}{.}{3} or D{.}{.}{5} to try aligning my decimal points. Some table did succeeded without affecting the header position, but some just ruined the whole table. The header just cannot stay in center of the cell.
Other problems are as described.

Please add a minimal, but compilable [mre] so that we can focus on solving the problem instead of creating a test file.
